# How to print document both side

Tags: c#

I have one command line application which print word document. As per new requirement, whenever application send document for printing, it should print both side.

So my question is, can I set in my C# program any printing property which send command to printer for print both side instead of doing manual with printer.

please advice
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.aspx

Perhaps you can use the Duplex-property?

Comment: In addition to the answer, here's the link to the Duplex enumeration to setup the printer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.duplex.aspx

Comment: @ahdaniels: thanks for your post let me check with the same and will update you soon

Comment: @ahdaniels: i have not yet implemented the code. got some major issues at my application fixing it :(
will surely update you :)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple piece of code to print with some settings:

```
var pd = new PrintDocument
{
    PrinterSettings =
    {
        Duplex = Duplex.Vertical,
        PrinterName = "YourPrinterName"
    }
};

if(pd.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
    pd.Print();
```