# how can print two file types double sided

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, duplex

What is the best way to print two different files double sided? (for example .docx and .pdf file). i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41371194/print-pdf-and-ms-word-files-in-one-print-job) using C# but i believe `ProcessStartInfo` doesn't work with `PrinterSettings.Duplex`. please any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print document both side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580032/how-to-print-document-both-side)

Comment: @NicoRiff its different problem. I cant use `ProcessStartInfo`  and `PrinterSettings.Duplex` setting together  when i use `ProcessStartInfo`,`PrinterSettings.Duplex` start not to work. if i dont use `ProcessStartInfo` in my code the print encrypt the content of .docx and .pdf

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: @TaW i am using winforms, i updated my question thanks