# How to set PrintTicket to turn on duplexing?

Tags: c#, xps

I'm supporting a C# app that prints XPS and modifies printer settings using PrintTickets. It's a **WPF** app, not a Windows Forms app, so any answer involving PrintDocument or PrintSettings is not relevant.

Most printer drivers that I've seen produce a `PrintCapabilities` xml document that contains `psk:JobDuplexAllDocumentsContiguously`. The related `PrintCapabilities.DuplexingCapability` object contains more than zero items and the `PrintTicket.Duplexing` member is non-null.

I've now seen more than one printer driver that returns PrintTicket and PrintCapabilities XML that uses the `psk:DocumentDuplex` keyword instead of `psk:JobDuplexAllDocumentsContiguously`. Problem is, once the XML has been deserialized into the corresponding .NET object, the `PrintCapabilites.DuplexingCapability` object contains zero items and the `PrintTicket.Duplexing` member is null. The printer can definitely do duplexing - it's just it doesn't report its capability as I've come to expect.

If I assign a value to `PrintTicket.Duplexing` then the xml for the PrintTicket then contains `psk:JobDuplexAllDocumentsContiguously` which the driver ignores.

I don't see how I can modify the `PrintTicket` object so that the related XML mentions `psk:DocumentDuplex`. Can anyone suggest what I should do?

**Edit**

I just discovered a crucial note in the MS documentation for [PrintTicket.Duplexing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.printticket.duplexing?view=netframework-4.8#remarks). The note says:

> This property corresponds to the Print Schema's
>   **JobDuplexAllDocumentsContiguously** keyword, not the **DocumentDuplex**
>   keyword.

This explains exactly what I'm seeing but I find this baffling. Why would MS put *two* duplex keywords in the PrintTicket schema but then write a class that implements only *one* of them?

To reiterate the original question - is there anything I can do to modify the `PrintTicket` object behaviour so that it understands `psk:DocumentDuplex`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print document both side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580032/how-to-print-document-both-side)

Comment: Look into [Duplex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.duplex?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Printing_PrinterSettings_Duplex) printing, and please provide the `C#` code that sets up and starts the print job.

Comment: After further inspection this does NOT look like a duplicate, because other questions do not cover XPS documents

Answer (score 0):

### C# Duplexing

You need to set the `Duplex` property of the `PrinterSettings` object.

> **Note:** You can use the [`CanDuplex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) property to check to see if the printer supports duplex printing.

**Sources**

- [PrinterSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [PrinterSettings.Duplex Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.duplex?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Printing_PrinterSettings_Duplex)
- [Duplex Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.duplex?view=netframework-4.7.2)

---

### XPS Duplexing

In `XPS` this should be possible setting the `Duplexing` property of a `PrintTicket`.

The documentation and [Printing Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/printing-overview) contains example code for Duplexing. *(Just search for `duplex` on the page)*

**Sources**

- [Printing Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/printing-overview)
- [PrintTicket Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.printticket?view=netframework-4.7.2#properties)
- [PrintTicket.Duplexing Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.printticket.duplexing?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Printing_PrintTicket_Duplexing)
- [Duplexing Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.duplexing?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Thanks for the response but PrinterSettings is for PrintDocument Windows Forms printing - not the XPS print path.

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS I have added information on XPS printing